# Why is the NVIDIA GPU so hot?

Tags: unity, 11.10, drivers, nvidia, temperature

I have just installed 11.10 and installed the recommended driver for NVIDIA (230M). The current driver installed is 280.13.

The temperature of the card is 85°C. I have tried using LXDE and Unity 2D, but the temperature does not drop. Once it did drop to 76°C, but even that's quite a lot.

Is there a fix to this? Do you think downgrading my driver would help? If so, how should I go about it?

Comment: Maybe the graphics card's fan is clogged up with dust or so? Did that happen before with 11.04?

Comment: Check the power mizer. Doe it show that the GPU and memory constantly run at top speed? If so, it might be a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The options initially available for additional drivers were as follows:

1. Nvidia accelerated graphics driver(version current) [Recommended]
2. Nvidia accelerated graphics driver(post-release updates)(version current-updates)

Initially I had installed 1. using which caused high temperature.Now, I have installed 2. I am not entirely sure if it was only because of the driver but doing this did solve it.

I hope someone explains as to what is the difference between the two clearly. This fixes the problem.

Comment: Version current is basically the version available with the Ubuntu release you're using (i.e. 11.10). Post-release, as it's name suggests, is update that was made available after the release. Bottom line is post-release is the newer driver that fixed the temperature issues you had with the current driver.

Comment: As far as I understand, @ArindamBiswas's answer did the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem with my Dell XPS L501X with GeForce GT 435M reporting temperatures of 96 - 97 and even touching 100 at one time resulting in shutdown.

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates` seems to have resolved it for now. Every Ubuntu update 10.04 - 10.10 -> 11.04 -> 11.10 i have been facing this temp problem.

UPDATE : Was still facing high GPU temperatures when i realized that the the air vents might be filled with dust. Blew some air with my vacuum  in short bursts and voila! the temperature hovers around 60-70. With skype audio/video and youtube, it does go up to 73 but that's a long way down from the 90-96 i was facing earlier.